# Django formatting DecimalField to money

Tags: python, django, formatting, currency

In my Django project I'm saving a money amount in a decimalField. The problem is the format of the number when I print it. I need it in the german money format 10.000,00 € so first a point as seperator and a comma for the cents. In Django I've only managed it to seperate everything with commas like 10,000,00

Has anyone an idea how I can implement it as I want?

Comment: Isn't the euro sign normally in front of the amount? This normally is done to prevent people from writing digits in front.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how about adding `intcomma` with [Humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/humanize/) maybe it can convert the number in to string containing commas every three digits.

Comment: @Adamu_Dee_Azare: well this will convert it with the locale of the user. But the question asks specifically for German.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the cleanest way will be to format this with the `locale`. First check if the German `locale` is supported on your system, for example with Debian:

```
$ locale -a
```

this will list all locale's, the name can very over different system. If the locale does not appear, you can generate one with:

```
$ sudo locale-gen de_DE
$ sudo locale-gen de_DE.utf8
$ sudo update-locale
```

Now we can work with this locale to format the number:

```
import locale


class MyModel(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)

    @property
    def as_money(self):
        locale.setlocale(local.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8')
        return locale.format('€ %.2f', self.amount, grouping=True, monetary=True)
```

You can then use this with a `MyModel` object `my_model` with `my_model.as_money`.

Normally the currency sign is put in front of the amount, to prevent people from writing digits in front (whereas writing digits at the end is often less of a problem).

Comment: That worked pretty good, thanks! The only problem now is that my number is display like that: 7.755,0 € , can I force it to have 2 digits at the end like "00". When I try using this %.2f my comma and point formatting gets messed up.

Comment: @FLYAX: what exactly is the result of `'%.2f'`? Note that this is `locale.format(..)`, and you need to set the locale first to `de_DE`.

Comment: When I use '%.2f' my formatting gets destroyed again and I just have 1 point before the last 2 digits again. I have LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de-de' in my settings. Is something missing there? Also I have this problem when I have numbers which are to long, the pogramm prints "79,983.79999999" insted of ".8"